# Округление числа в C# более чем на 15 знаков

Tags: c#, .net

Могу ли я округлить число более чем на 15 знаков после запятой ?

```
public static double GetSumTwo(int n)
    {
        double y = 1;
        double sum1 = 0;
        double sum2 = 0;

        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        {
            while (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum2 += -(y / (x * (x + 1)));
                break;
            }

            while (x % 2 != 0)
            {
                sum1 += y / (x * (x + 1));
                break;
            }
        }

        double sum = sum1 + sum2;
        decimal result = Math.Round((decimal)sum, 16);

        return (double)result;
    }
```

Expected: 0.38217893217893217d 
But was:  0.38217893217893201d

Comment: А зачем округлять? Расскажите, какая ваша реальная проблема.

Comment: У double всего точность 15 знаков. Если вам нужна большая точность, double вам не подходит

Comment: У double значащая часть до 51 бита, что и дает точность до 15 знаков.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартно в языке такого нет, используйте nuget-пакет: Fractions